# enum in Q_PROPERTY is not shown

Tags: c++, qt, enums

I have following code:

```
class QtPhysicalComponentAdapter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

    Q_PROPERTY(QMaterials FrictionMaterial READ frictionMaterial WRITE setFrictionMaterial DESIGNABLE true USER true)


    Q_ENUMS(QMaterials)

public:

    enum QMaterials
    {
      None,
      Glass,
      Iron
    };

    QtPhysicalComponentAdapter(CPhysicalComponent* pAdapter):
       m_pAdapter(pAdapter)
    {}

    virtual ~QtPhysicalComponentAdapter(void) {};

    QMaterials frictionMaterial() const
    {
       // Just debug code
       return static_cast<QMaterials>(0);
    }

    void setFrictionMaterial(QMaterials newMat)
    {
       // Just debug code
       m_pAdapter->SetFrictionMaterial(static_cast<CFrictionTable::Material>(0));
     }

private:

     CPhysicalComponent* m_pAdapter;
}
```

Actually, I have some other Q_PROPERTY in this class, but they have basic types like int, float, etc.. The problem is that if I try to add Q_PROPERTY with enum it compiles fine, but this property is not shown. I can't find any error in the build output. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Where do you want to see it?

Comment: I want to see it at my GUI

Comment: I do not understand what you mean with _my GUI_. In the QtDesigner when you edit your `.ui` files? Or in qml?

Comment: I think in qml. I am sorry, I am new in Qt. Here is a [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwJvEZNySmxvMEVHMnlLY2dFTEk/view?usp=sharing) of app that I have, area in the red circle is where it suppose to be. Maybe it is some way to check Qt errors that I have during compilation?

Comment: How did you made the property editor? (please add essential information to your original question instead of adding it in a comment)